# How to add multiple array elements into a transposed structure?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have these arrays

```php
$months = ['jan', 'feb'];

$cashUniform = [2000, 1200];

$cashFee = [24000, 34000];

$cashExpenses = [4000, 300];
```

Am trying to create an object from these arrays like so:

```
$data = [{
 'month': 'jan',
 'cashUniform': 2000,
 'cashFee': 24000,
 'cashExpenses': 4000,
},
{
 'month': 'feb',
 'cashUniform': 12000,
 'cashFee': 34000,
 'cashExpenses': 300,
 }
];
```

I've tried array_combine but it only accepts two array elements, and in my case, I have four array elements.

I've also tried to to create a multiple array.

```
  $data['months'] = $months;
  $data['cashFee'] = $cashFee;
  $data['cashUniform'] = $cashUniform;
  $data['cashExpenses'] = $cashExpenses;
  dd(json_encode($data));
```

The code above returns

```
{"months":["JAN","FEB"],"cashFee":   [12500,2000],"cashUniform":[2000,0],"cashExpenses":[1500,0]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to loop over all arrays and add the values to a single array:

```
$data = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($months); $i++) {
    $data[] = [
        'month' => $monts[$i],
        'cashUniform' => $cashUniform[$i],
        'cashFee' => $cashFee[$i],
        'cashExpenses' => $cashExpenses[$i],
    ];
}

dd($data);
```

This does require that all arrays have the same amount of values!

Comment: It worked well. Thanks @Jerodev . Then I do `json_encode($data)`. I get an object like `"[{"date":"Jul","cashUniform":2000,"cashFee":12500,"cashExpenses":1500,"allUniform":2000},{"date":"Aug","cashUniform":0,"cashFee":2000,"cashExpenses":0,"allUniform":0}] ◀"

`. Then I try to loop the object using for each loop but I get this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I notice the object is in double-quotes. How do I solve this?

Comment: There is no need to `json_encode` the array before using it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [];
foreach ($months as $index => $value) {
$data[] = [
        'month' => $monts[$index],
        'cashUniform' => $cashUniform[$index],
        'cashFee' => $cashFee[$index],
        'cashExpenses' => $cashExpenses[$index],
    ]; 
} 
dd($data);
```

Comment: Although it is a basic snippet, this answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about some elegant functional programming so that you don't need to declare a global result array?  Transpose the individually declared input data using `array_map()` -- this synchronously iterates each array.  Then name the custom function's parameters to align with the desired keys in the output's subarrays.  Use `compact()` to avoid manually re-writing the keys and variables in the `return` line.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bl7fY))

```
$months = ['jan', 'feb'];
$cashUniform = [2000, 1200];
$cashFee = [24000, 34000];
$cashExpenses = [4000, 300];

var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($month, $cashUniform, $cashFee, $cashExpenses) {
            return compact(['month', 'cashUniform', 'cashFee', 'cashExpenses']);
        },
        $months,
        $cashUniform,
        $cashFee,
        $cashExpenses
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'jan',
    'cashUniform' => 2000,
    'cashFee' => 24000,
    'cashExpenses' => 4000,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'feb',
    'cashUniform' => 1200,
    'cashFee' => 34000,
    'cashExpenses' => 300,
  ),
)
```